# Find the fatal flaw in this google maps javascript code?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Some of this code is borrowed, so I have a little trouble following it due to unfamiliarity with the process of converting an image to a draggable and codable object in the map.

This is part of a phonegap webapp. When run, I see the map and I see the marker image, which I can then drag around-- however, when I drop it, it does not fasten to the map and become clickable for event triggering as in the original example I modeled it after. Can anyone spot any raging flaws?

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />

        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style type="text/css">
                html { height: 100% }
                body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
                #map { height: 100% }
                </style>


            <!-- iPad/iPhone specific css below, add after your main css >
             <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" type="text/css" />       
             <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" />      
             -->
            <!-- If your application is targeting iOS BEFORE 4.0 you MUST put json2.js from http://www.JSON.org/json2.js into your www directory and include it here -->
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">


                function onBodyLoad()
                {       
                    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
                }

                /* When this function is called, PhoneGap has been initialized and is ready to roll */
                /* If you are supporting your own protocol, the var invokeString will contain any arguments to the app launch.
                 see http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
                 for more details -jm */


            <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAHvl0q_ICxMdoioV8TAVeDhT3Rnec_7H_Z7LsYhQbN1_UW7UedxRVF7XTuKiZUL-yUwkvJri9Ou5rRQ" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script>

                    <script>
                        function centerAndZoomOnBounds(bounds) {
                            var center = bounds.getCenter();
                            var newZoom = map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds);
                            if (map.getZoom() != newZoom) {
                                map.setCenter(center, newZoom);
                            } else {
                                map.panTo(center);
                            }
                        }

                        function createMarker(p) {
                            var m = new GMarker(p);
                            GEvent.addListener(m,"click",function(){this.openInfoWindow(p.toUrlValue())});
                            return m;
                        }

                        function addMarkerToMap() {
                            // find location of point
                            var markerPointx = this.left+10; // left+half the width;
                            var markerPointy = this.top+34 ;  // top + height;
                            var markerPoint = map.fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new GPoint(markerPointx,markerPointy));
                            // add marker
                            var m1 = createMarker(markerPoint);
                            map.addOverlay(m1);
                            // move draggable back to start
                            marker.moveTo(new GPoint(16,110));
                        }

                    </script>




            </head>


    <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">

        <p><big><a href="InputCoordinates.html">Back</a></big></p>


        <div id="map" width=100% height=100%>
            <br><p style="padding-left:25px" id="message">You should be seeing a Google Map here.</p>

        </div>

        <img src="http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/marker.png" id="imgMarker">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[

                var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map");
                var map = new GMap2(mapdiv);

                map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
                map.addControl(new GScaleControl());
                map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(52.019029,-0.770427), 6, G_NORMAL_MAP);

                marker = new GDraggableObject(document.getElementById("imgMarker"));
                marker.moveTo(new GPoint(16,110));
                GEvent.addListener(marker,"dragend",addMarkerToMap);

                //]]>
            </script>

        <!--Maps API Key
         AIzaSyD52tRfTY1FtEgXQpvu9-jN5AOz-2pxQg0
         -->
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the onload method on the body points to a non existent function: initialize();

Also,  the map initialization code needs to be done inside of a function that is called when the body onload event fires, so that the necessary dom elements are guaranteed to have been created.

Here is a basic example that shows about the simplest maps initialization that can be run.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: Also, the opening <html> and <head> tags are not included in the document you posted,  not sure that is a copy past error, or an issue with your original source.

Comment: Yeah the missing tags are a copy/paste error. However, the other portion is intentional but not understood. In one of my other maps pages, which I wrote myself, I do have an initialize function and the whole thing works well. In this fellow's example which I partially copied, however, there is no initialize, but it still works anyway. Can you explain what the difference is if it works either way?

Comment: I would have to see the code from the other example to be able to tell you.  A big part of it is timing though.  As long as the DOM elements exist, than they are available to be accessed by script, if the elements are not yet part of the DOM, than trying access them via script will fail.  This is a big reason why the document reday function in jquery has become so popular, it abstracts all of the timing out the initialization process.